# How to get a single record in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, one-to-many

In a one-to-many relationship, `users` have many `contracts`. However, I only want the most recent contract for a specific set of users.

My query to get all contracts for users look like this:

```
SELECT userid FROM contract 
WHERE userid IN (123, 143, 153, 163);
```

I naively thought the following query could return the most recent contract for the 4 users in the `WHERE` clause. However, it only limits to 1 record for the entire result set.

```
SELECT userid FROM contract 
WHERE userid IN (123, 143, 153, 163)
ORDER BY signingdate DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

How can I fix my query to get the latest records that have a one-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to make a subselect or with common table expression query (CTE), then the following will work for you. This numbers the results within each user ID, ordering by the signing date.

```
 select userId from (
       select userId, 
              row_number() over (partition by userId order by signingdate desc) as rnDmy
       from contract
       where userId in (123, 143, 153, 163)
      ) where rnDmy = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should Work

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid, 
MAX(signingdate) OVER (PARTITION BY userid) 
FROM contract 
where userid in (123, 143, 153, 163)
```

UPDATE: added DISTINCT to eliminate possibility of duplicates

Comment: FYI, this will still cause multiple records to be displayed per userId. The user implies from their question that they only wanted a single row per user (most recent).

Comment: @Bradd the only way that can happen is, if there are multiple rows for the same userid on the same signing date. That is fixed by adding a `DISTINCT` 
You dont need a nested select, if thats what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `limit and offset` use [select distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html):

```
select distinct on(userid) 
       userid
     , signingdate
  from contract 
 where userid in (123, 143, 153, 163)
order by userid
       , signingdate desc;
```